# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_assert_univariate' Dart check_seasonality error

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dart, time-series

This is the code:

```
for m in range(2, 100):
    is_seasonal, period = check_seasonality(train, m=m, alpha=.05)
    if is_seasonal:
        print('There is seasonality of order {}.'.format(period))
```

Dataset:

```
      Time    country   customer    brand   category    gmv_actual
54  2020-01-14  0    0  16  0   71425.011246    
55  2020-01-14  0   0   2   1   1904.592675 
56  2020-01-14  0   0   4   1   1777.309036 
57  2020-01-14  0   0   21  1   912.792411  
58  2020-01-14  0   0   24  2   196.505411
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much code. but a quick note that I can give is that **check_seasonality**
takes a Time series object not a data frame.

Comment: As it stands now, this question belongs more to a comment in my opinion. You could add more info to make a more comprehensive answer

Comment: I can't add comments, for now. just wanted to give some help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33469996)